# SUM row field MEDOO

Tags: php, mysql, sum, right-join, medoo

I am trying to get a summed field in medoo.

My sql at the moment is like:

```
$database->debug()->select("user_rupees_in_house", [
    "[<]rupees" => ["rupee_id" => "ID"]
], [
    "name",
    "amount",
    "amount_spend"
], [
    "user_uuid"  => $user,
    "GROUP" => "rupee_id"
]);
```

The debug logs the following statement:

```
SELECT `name`,`amount`,`amount_spend`, `rupee_id`
FROM `user_rupees_in_house` 
RIGHT JOIN `rupees` 
ON `user_rupees_in_house`.`rupee_id` = `rupees`.`ID` 
WHERE `user_uuid` = '4da9ff11-56ca3a2f-b3ab-a25b9230'
GROUP BY `rupee_id`
```

What I'm trying to achieve is:

```
SELECT `name`,SUM(`amount`),SUM(`amount_spend`), `rupee_id`
FROM `user_rupees_in_house` 
RIGHT JOIN `rupees` 
ON `user_rupees_in_house`.`rupee_id` = `rupees`.`ID` 
WHERE `user_uuid` = '4da9ff11-56ca3a2f-b3ab-a25b9230'
GROUP BY `rupee_id`
```

Does anybody know how to make this statement in medoo?

[EDIT 1]

Found another way of achieving this

```
// Get the rupee types
$rupee_types = $database->select("rupees", "ID");

foreach ($rupee_types as $rupee_type) {
    $amount = $database->sum("user_rupees_in_house", "amount", [
        "AND" => [
            "rupee_id" => $rupee_type,
            "user_uuid" => $user
        ]
    ]);

    // Build array of rupees
}
```

This will make a lot more calls to the database, but is working just fine as long as the `SELECT` statement does not support aggregate functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Medoo` doesn't support aggregate function in `SELECT` statement. Use `raw` query instead.

Try this:

```
$result = $database->query(
    "SELECT `name`,SUM(`amount`),SUM(`amount_spend`), `rupee_id`
    FROM `user_rupees_in_house` 
    RIGHT JOIN `rupees` 
    ON `user_rupees_in_house`.`rupee_id` = `rupees`.`ID` 
    WHERE `user_uuid` = '$user'
    GROUP BY `rupee_id`"
)->fetchAll();
```

[Reference](http://www.sitepoint.com/getting-started-medoo-examples-use/)

Comment: This will result in: SELECT "name","" AS "amount","" AS "amount_spend" FROM "user_rupees_in_house" RIGHT JOIN "rupees" ON "user_rupees_in_house"."rupee_id" = "rupees"."ID" WHERE "user_uuid" = '4da9ff11-56ca3a2f-b3ab-a25b9230' GROUP BY "rupee_id"

Comment: Sorry. It's my mistake. `Medoo` doesn't support aggregate function in `select` statement. You can use raw query instead. will Rectify my post.

Comment: this works, only needed to add '->fetchAll()' after the statement. But there must be a better way with using the medoo class (?)

Comment: Current version doesn't support aggregate functions in `SELECT` statement. But you can use `sum` method as shown in reference link in my post.

Comment: Prever to make just one statment, but thanks for your help :D